# Loading Data into DropDownList very slow - asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance

I'm trying to fill a dropdownlist with data. But the this simple code snipped takes up to 6 seconds:

```
     for (int i = 0; i < users.Count; i++)
        {
            var user = users[i];
            cbHead.Items.Add(new ListItem(user.DisplayName, user.Username));
            cbFirstStageHandler.Items.Add(new ListItem(user.DisplayName, user.Username));
            cbSecondStageHandler.Items.Add(new ListItem(user.DisplayName, user.Username));
        }
```

I don't understand this loading time. Doing the same stuff in WPF takes just a couple of milliseconds.
There are 167 entries in the users list.

Thanks

**EDIT:**
The problem was pretty stupid. The `User` object has a property called `DisplayName` which loads the displayname from the Active Directory on every call.

Comment: How did you measure the time, second thing in ASP.net there is request time will be involved and initializing controls will take some time so that WPF.  If you are so upset form the time. Do the binding in client side.

Comment: did you check the connection string?

Comment: breakpoints. it's not the initializing of the page

Comment: users ist filled at this point. there is no connection needed here

Comment: How do you measure it takes 6 seconds? 6 seconds take to execut this for loop code or loading on your UI? More details required to understand.

Comment: 6 sekonds for executing this loop. i set a breakpoint at the beginning and at the end.